# Python-mode import problem

Tags: python, emacs

I'm trying to use Emacs as a python editor and it works fine when I evaluate(C-c C-c) only single files but when I evaluate a file that imports another file in the same directory, I get an error saying that the file could not be imported.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Thanks in advance

edit: Btw, i'm using Emacs23 on a Ubuntu machine.

The error was,

```
  ImportError: No module named hlutils
```

Comment: I am not trying to disrespect you, I am only saying this because I have never had problems like this, and I just want to make sure of yours, but when you try running the file normally with python, outside of emacs, it does run correctly, right?

Comment: Also, try running the following python code:

import os
print os.listdir('.')

and see what folder it prints out.

Comment: Yes, I wrote it in Scite and it worked. I'm switching to emacs because its a little more dynamic (its got a repl to test code out quickly whereas scite just runs a python command and shows the output).










                                                                                                                                                  No offence taken of course :)

Comment: I'd guess that it's set the current working directory to something other than that which you expect. Use `os.getcwd()` to figure out where you've really been dumped...

Comment: hi, i tried that command but it seems that the current directory is correct.

Comment: What happens when you `print sys.path`? Is the directory containing `hlutils` in `sys.path`?

Comment: no, it isn't in the sys.path, but this just an small app, would i have to add my folder to the sys.path variable everytime to make it recognizable?

Comment: I have an idea about how to fix the problem. See my edit, below.

Comment: Your REPL is started in the context of the file from which you start the REPL. Consider structure to your development process. If you'd add a bunch of different contexts to your REPL, what you write in it may be confusing.

Answer (score 16):

I think the problem is in the way Emacs' python-mode runs Python.  If I type `M-x run-python`, then I see this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> '' in sys.path
False
>>>
```

whereas if I run the python interpreter from the shell, I see:

```
>>> import sys
>>> '' in sys.path
True
>>>
```

This seems to be due to the following code in `run-python` from progmodes/python.el:

```
(let* ((cmdlist
    (append (python-args-to-list cmd)
        '("-i" "-c" "import sys; sys.path.remove('')")))
```

which has no comment, and the following helpful ChangeLog entry:

```
2008-08-24  Romain Francoise  <romain@orebokech.com>

        * progmodes/python.el (run-python): Remove '' from sys.path.
```

I would say this is a bug in Emacs. Here's a workaround that you could put in your .emacs file:

```
(defun python-reinstate-current-directory ()
  "When running Python, add the current directory ('') to the head of sys.path.
For reasons unexplained, run-python passes arguments to the
interpreter that explicitly remove '' from sys.path. This means
that, for example, using `python-send-buffer' in a buffer
visiting a module's code will fail to find other modules in the
same directory.

Adding this function to `inferior-python-mode-hook' reinstates
the current directory in Python's search path."
  (python-send-string "sys.path[0:0] = ['']"))

(add-hook 'inferior-python-mode-hook 'python-reinstate-current-directory)
```

Comment: According to http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/cvstoys-list/2003q3/000114.html - it was a "security fix", other info here: http://old.nabble.com/python.el:-why-remove-%27%27-from-sys.path--td22502790.html

Answer (score 12):

Since the answers previous to this one were posted an option was made available to change the default behaviour (removing the current directory from the path) to include the cwd in the path.

So a simple

```
(setq python-remove-cwd-from-path nil)
```

in your .emacs should fix this.

Comment: You can also set this variable in your **.emacs** file via `M-x customize-variable [RET] python-remove-cwd-from-path [RET]`.

Answer (score 1):

I import local modules from the same directory just fine when using `py-execute-buffer`.

Your problem might be related to the way `py-execute-buffer` goes about its work: it saves the buffer to a tmp file (in the directory `py-temp-directory`) and then it passes this file to Python. In your case, the system might be affected by the temp file directory.

Another aspect: `py-execute-buffer` does different things with the tmp file depending on whether a Python interpreter buffer exists or not. Try your case with a running interpreter and without (just kill the interpreter buffer).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, if you don't want to edit your .emacs file you can put this at the beginning of your script:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
```

It adds the current working dirrectory to your sys.path temporarily,

Comment: Note: You may want to add the current working directory to the beginning of your path with sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type `emacs -q`. This starts an emacs without loading the init file (`.emacs`). Does the same behavior occur? If not, then it means there is a problem in your .emacs file.

**Edit:**

When you run a script using C-c C-c from within Emacs' Python mode, the directory containing the script is *not* added to the beginning of `sys.path`. I found this out by putting

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

at the top of a test script. This is why Python is not finding other modules that reside in the same directory.

When you run the script from the command-line, Python does add the directory containing the script to `sys.path`. That's why the same script works from the command-line.

You can fix this by editing your ~/.bashrc file and adding

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/Python/scripts
```

After saving ~/.bashrc, close emacs and start it again to make sure the change to .bashrc becomes effective.

Comment: Is the scripts directory the directory to my file or is it a special folder in python?

i tried path/to/python as /usr/share/python but it didnt work.

sorry am new to linux, in windows i know that my python folder is in c:/python25, but linux has many folders named python hence i can't make out the correct one

Comment: @smith, sorry I should have been more clear. Change `/path/to/Python/scripts` to the directory that contains `hlutils.py`.

Comment: hiya, i edited the .bashrc file but it still wouldn't work even after trying some alternatives like PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/desktop/project 
export PYTHONPATH .

My fate i guess :( . Thanks a lot for your suggestions and patience, on the bright side I learnt something about my folder structure :)

Comment: Hm, sorry then. I thought I had this one nailed... :-/

Answer (score 0):

I am really quite bad with emacs lisp, and I have never used Ubuntu, so the following may require some tweaking, but if the code runs fine from the shell, why not just set emacs to run the shell command? Just put:

```
(defun shell-compile ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command (concat "python " (buffer-file-name))))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "\C-c\C-c") 'shell-compile)))
```

into your .emacs file. There must be much cleaner ways to do it, but this will at least get you working.

Comment: Thanks, this works good. But instead of executing a shell command if it starts a python interpreter and sends the buffer contents to the python interpreter it would be great, thats the one feature that python-mode offers that i really want, just can't get it to work ;)

Answer (score 0):

improving an existing answer above: eval this in your scratch buffer to add cwd back onto pythonpath

```
(defun python-reinstate-current-directory ()
  (python-send-string "sys.path[0:0] = ['']"))
(add-hook 'inferior-python-mode-hook 'python-reinstate-current-directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a very easy solution. 
Just add to your `.emacs` the following single line:

```
(setenv "PYTHONPATH" "/path/to/where/modules/are")
```

It will set the value of the environment variable named variable to value.

Now, typing in emacs python interpreter...

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
>>> ['/path/to/where/modules/are', '/usr/share/emacs/23.1/etc' ... ]
```

...and the custom `import`s work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I noticed that when I use the run-python command in Emacs, it runs the default Python version (2.7) on my Ubuntu build. That's not right. I installed Anaconda. When I start Python from a command line, it starts my Anaconda installation (3.7).

Check out James Anderson's answer on this post:

[Emacs and condo workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175916/emacs-and-conda-workaround)

He's right in my case. If I start Emacs from the command line, Emacs knows about the hijacked path Anaconda added. I'm sure I could get that into my Emacs initialization somehow if I cared.