# Emacs and conda workaround

Tags: python, emacs, conda

I'm using emacs and anaconda.

I have this in my init.el:

```
(setenv "WORKON_HOME" "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/")
```

And conda on my path:

```
# added by Anaconda3 installer
export PATH="/home/user/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

but emacs can't find my conda environments, which I understand it is supposed to be able to do..

So, when I run `C-c C-p` to start a new session, and `C-c C-c`, it fails to import my packages  which are installed in a conda environment, with `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Since I have added this to my path and it still doesn't work, I am trying to work around this, and still be able to run my conda applications from emacs.

I can open a *shell* in emacs with `M-x shell`, then `source activate myenv`, and run `python`.

I now want `C-c C-c` to copy into /this/ *shell*.  How do I mark this *shell* *buffer* as a python process to send my file.py's text to on C-c C-c, rather than just a shell *shell*?

### Update1

I've also looked at the following references:

- https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20092/using-conda-environments-in-emacs
- [How does conda-env list / conda info --envs find environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152384/how-does-conda-env-list-conda-info-envs-find-environments)

But neither package works for me.  I still get, when I try:

```
conda-env-list

*Conda envs*
```

Produces a blank buffer.

And this for pyvenv-workon:

```
pyvenv-workon
  Work on:  (empty)
```

These environments very much exist, and it makes it impossible to use emacs as a python IDE if I can't run my code.

Comment: Not completely sure, but look at Emacs' `exec-path` variable, this is where Emacs is searching for programs to run. As for loading a virtual environment, what works for me is calling `pyvenv-activate`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I found works for me is to use the `conda` package from ELPA and set two of its configuration variables to point to my Conda directory. The following snippet does the trick in my `.emacs`:

```lisp
(use-package conda
  :ensure t
  :init
  (setq conda-anaconda-home (expand-file-name "~/miniconda3"))
  (setq conda-env-home-directory (expand-file-name "~/miniconda3")))
```

- `conda-anaconda-home` is the equivalent to the `ANACONDA_HOME` environment variable (i.e. contains all files of your Anaconda installation)
- `conda-env-home-directory` - is the directory where your virtual environments get stored (within the `envs` subdirectory)

With this configuration I'm able to run <kbd>M-x conda-env-activate</kbd> and have access to all previously created envs.

Comment: This did it for me.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, but now, when activating a env, it says `Searching for program: No such file or directory, python` after running `run-python`, it seems not to be finding python.exe withing the env.

Comment: @ElBaulP, sounds like a `PATH` problem. Try adding something like this to your `.emacs`:
`(add-to-list 'exec-path "~/miniconda3/bin")`
`(setenv "PATH" "~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH" '("PATH"))`

Comment: @WojciechGac Thanks!, I do not have a `bin/` subdirectory, but `~/miniconda3` worked, as `python.exe` is within it.

Comment: @WojciechGac Thanks a lot! My problem was that I had the `(setq conda-env-home-directory ...)` under `:config` instead of `:init`. Thank you! Your post brought me to the problem.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 8):

Programs inherit the environment variables from the shell that spawned them.  The way conda and virtualenv work is by overriding the shell's PATH variable.  They do this so that the OS finds the new version of the app (conda's or virtualenv's) instead of the default one installed with the OS (Macs come with an ancient version of python).

So, what is happening here?  If you start Emacs by double clicking on the OS icon it will inherit the default shell environment variables.  So when you try to call a library that you installed with conda (or equivalently with virtualenv and pip), because you are using the default OS path, the OS is finding the default version of python (and crucially the default version's libraries).  The default version of python is going to respond "I have no idea what library that is."

How to fix?  One reliable way is to *not* start Emacs by double clicking on the OS Icon.  Here is what I do most days:

```
1) start a console/terminal
2) switch to the conda environment `activate py37` 
    (or with virtualenv: `source .py37dev/bin/activate`)
3) start Emacs from that same shell that has the modified environment variables.  
    On a Mac its: `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` 
    (I use a installed version of Emacs on the Mac because the one that 
    comes with Mac is ancient).  
    On Linux and Windows the path to EMacs will be different but the idea is the same.
4) start a shell inside Emacs and you should see the shell looks the way it does 
    in your conda shell (or virtualenv shell)
```

here it what it looks like for me:
[image]

see how the version of python is not the default OS python?  Its the one from the virtualenv + pip environment (conda works the exact same way, just the start envirmonment is a different command)

Comment: How do you manage switching between different python projects that may be in different conda environments?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the solutions given in the answers of [Wojciech Gac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1071468/wojciech-gac), of [Mittenchops](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1052117/mittenchops) and [James Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4763676/james-anderson).

While solution of [James Anderson's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55184644/8799635) is by far the easiest, it comes with a few problems:
First, you have to reactivate the environment in each shell process you spawn in emacs. There is also the possibility that emacs has a different pythonpath, therefor reluctantly using system python and not `venv` python.

The solution with `conda.el` is somehow weird. In Melpa it is listed as obsolete and with instructions of https://github.com/necaris/conda.el it won't recognize the environments on my certain machine.

On the same machine the solution with `pyenv` as mentioned in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20093/28567 is working like a charm.

Therefor you only need to install with `M-x package-install` search for `pyenv` and then insert following two lines into `.emacs`:

```
(setenv "WORKON_HOME" "~/anaconda3/envs") ; /anaconda3 || /miniconda || wathever path your conda installation is located at
(pyvenv-mode 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my minimal solution to this problem:

create a batch file like this

```
conda activate <yourEnv>
python -i
```

set (local) python-shell-interpreter pointing to the batch-file

run-python as always (C-c C-p ...)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly an answer to your question. But If you JUST want to run your code, open the directory in the terminal where your files are located (e.g. `cd /Downloads/Chapter01/yourfile.py`) . Then, activate the environment (`conda activate *your env*`) and pass this command (`python yourfile.py`). Your code will be executed within that environment by python.
I edit remote files with emacs and run code like this in another terminal window. You may wanna open the two terminal windows side by side while debugging your code.