# Emacs gud-pdb with miniconda python environments

Tags: python, emacs, miniconda

How does one get emacs to use the same PATH to the python and pdb executables as I get from the term when I have set a specific miniconda environment?

I.e. in emacs, when I run `M-x pdb`, I would like it to use the same executable as I do if I have done the following from the term:

```
$ source activate my_py3_env
$ pdb
```

I know currently this isn't what is happening. I switch to a python 3 env, which modifies my PATH appropriately, but when I run `M-x pdb` for a python script and print sys.version from within that script I get:

```
2.7.17 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 21 2019, 19:04:46)
```

So it seems to be picking up the 'base' miniconda env which is still 2.7

I would half of expected it to pick up whats in /usr/bin but that doesn't seem to be the case, i.e. if I execute:

```
$ /usr/bin/python
```

I get

```
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:39:04)
```

To summarise, is there a way to get emacs `M-x pdb` to 'follow' the conda environment I am currently in without me having to manually specify the location of the pdb executable for each environment?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175916/emacs-and-conda-workaround/55184644#55184644

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `conda` or virtualenv python path with (swap in the analogous conda equivalent for starting the env): 
`source .py2james/bin/activate` 
and 
`which python` in the terminal.  Note the path to the python exe.

you can do: <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> pdb

then: `/Users/janderson/code/python/awsomeapp/.py2james/bin/python -m pdb main.py` and the emacs pdb debugger will start.